# Showing $n! = \sqrt{2\pi n} (\frac{n}{e})^n \big(1 + \mathcal{O}(\frac{1}{n})\big)$ from $\log(n!) =n\log(n) - n + \mathcal{O}\big(\log(n)\big)$

Tags: analytic-number-theory

I wish to prove Stirling's Formula in this way, in particular showing the first term in the series is $\mathcal{O}\big(\frac{1}{n}\big)$, and I've come across a "proof" that simply states there is "more work needed" between these two statements, and I can't work out how to do it. Would really appreciate any help, thanks.

Comment: The $\implies$ in the title does not hold.

Comment: You need more. $\log (n!) = n\log n - n + \mathcal{O}(\log n)$ is not sufficient to prove Stirling's formula. You need $\log (n!) = \left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right) \log n - n + \frac{1}{2}\log (2\pi) + \mathcal{O}\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$. But then it's pretty direct.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, I know that's what I'm aiming for, but I don't know how to get there?

Comment: Go back to the start, and prove the asymptotics that you need. The very coarse $n\log n - n + \mathcal{O}(\log n)$ doesn't help you.